# Uncaught type Error: b is undefined. How to resolve such errors?

Tags: javascript

I was solving Euler problem no 48 and arrived at the solution-. Basically I tried to calculate self powers storing their digits in an array. The link to the question is https://projecteuler.net/problem=48
However I am getting an unexpected error. The error message displayed is `Uncaught error b is undefined`

```
function selfPower(n,b)
{
    var carry,i=1,j;
    b[0][n-1]=1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        carry=0,j=0;
        while(b[j])
        {
            b[j][n-1]=b[j][n-1]*n+carry;
            carry= Math.floor(b[j][n-1]/10);
            b[j][n-1]%=10;
            j++;
        }
        while(carry>0){
            b[j][n-1]=carry;
            carry=Math.floor(b[j][n-1]/10);
            b[j][n-1]%=10;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
var a=[][1000];
var str="";
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++){
    selfPower(i,a);
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=1;j<1000;j++)
    a[i][0]+=a[i][j];

    a[i][0]+=carry;
    carry=Math.floor(a[i][0]/10);
    a[i][0]%=10;
    str=a[i][0]+str;
}
document.getElementById('output').textContent= str;
```

However I am getting an error on line no 4 giving `Uncaught Typeerror: b is undefined.`
How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you expect the result of `[][1000]` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Their is flaw in the way the array has been initialized in the above code

If you want to be able access the matrix like so matrix[i][j]

I find it the most convenient to initialize it in a loop.

```
var matrix = [],
    cols = 3;

//init the grid matrix
for ( var i = 0; i < cols; i++ ) {
    matrix[i] = []; 
}
```

this will give you [ [], [], [] ]

so matrix[0][0] matrix[1][0] return undefined and not the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

So if you rewrite the code it will be

```
var a=[]
var i,j;
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++){
    a[i-1]=[];
    a[i-1][0]=1;
    selfPower(i,a);
}
```

This will resolve the problem